# How to get background images to scale to the same size in Xcode Autolayout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode7

### The Problem:

I am currently trying to get the background image of launch page of my app and the first view controller to match in size.

On left, launch screen on the right first view controller.

[image: On left launch screen on the right first view controller.]

However as you can see the navigation bar appears to resize the background image.

Both back ground images are currently set to centre vertically and horizontally and both have equal width and height to the view.

### What Ive tried

I have obviously tried messing around with auto layout to now avail,
I have also tried toggling the Extend Edges “under Top Bars” option, it is currently set to true in the above image. This didn't work either.

### Question

How do I get both background images to have the same sizes (consistent) between the launch screen and the first view controller, for all iPhone devices (in auto layout)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for anyone with this problem.

Tick extend edges under Opaque bars for the view controller.